# Create a sharable URL for a room NodeJS + Socketio

Tags: html, node.js, url, socket.io

I am in the process of creating a lobby where it should redirect the user to a game room with a url such as site.com/1234, where *1234* is the room code using Node.js and Socket.io. I have gotten to the step where when the user presses a button a request to the server is sent to connect to a room with a random room code. A message should then be sent back containing the url so that I may do `window.location = url`. This should result in the correct link and send the user to a new HTML file.

The problem that I now have is that I have no clue on how to generate such a url or how to show the next html page after the request gets approved. I have seen some people say that I can do `app.get("/:gameID")` but I lack the knowledge to implement it properly.

I have seen some other posts asking about this but the answers are either very vague or they are using some frame work. I would appreciate if someone could nudge me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I did it was by, like you said, setting up a route that allows you to have a parameter

```
app.get('/chat/:id', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('./public/chat/chat.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Then client side, trim the url and use socket.io to emit the room

```
let t = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
// on connection, tries to login to the chat with the chat ID made
socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.emit('loginchat', {id: t});
});
```

Server side again:

```
   socket.on('loginchat', async function(data){
      socket.room = data.id;
      //console.log(socket.room)
      socket.join(data.id);
   });
```

so when a user accesses the /chat route with a param, the server will access it, and send them to the appropriate room.

I wrote this a bit fast so apologies for any confusing bits, if you are stuck on part of it let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Ive read up on it a bit more and im wondering is there a purpose for you to send the code from the client instead of doing **const roomID = req.params.roomID;** within the app.get function (2nd code block)?

Comment: On a separate note do you know if I am able to place socket.on() etc. inside the app.get function? I feel like it looks neater but Im not sure if it is against coding standards or if it will mess everything up

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "send code from the client", but in response to your second question, you can, providing you set io before a route, so for me, let io = socket(server) is above the /chat route, so I can block access if too many clients are connected at once, if you define io before a route, you can access it. Whether that means you need to do io.on and then socket.on i'm not sure of

Comment: Ah by code I meant the roomID, but now that I think about it both seem fine. Thanks for the responses :D

Comment: No worries, I'm glad my old code was of use to you :)